# When I add padding the sizeToFit() method misses the last line of the UILabel, how do I fix this?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, xcode7.3

Custom class:

```
class FancyLabel: UILabel {

  let padding  = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)

  override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    super.drawTextInRect(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, padding))
   }
}
```

In my view controller:

```
let myframe = CGRectMake(10, 10, some_width, some_height)
let myLabel = FancyLabel(frame: myframe)
myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
myLabel.text = text
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0
myLabel.sizeToFit()
self.myScrollView.addSubview(myLabel)
```

The result is this:

[The last line of the UILabel is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATKei.png)

Comment: what happens if you make "some_height" arbitrarily large, like "`32767`"?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann No difference even after I give it `CGFloat.max`